# how to stop esxtop gracefully which is running in batch mode?

Tags: bash, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, gzip

I am running esxtop in batch mode using the below command:

```
esxtop –b –a –d 10 –n 2000| gzip -9c > perfData.csv.gz
```

This is going to run for a little over 5 hrs, but I want to stop it gracefully and get my perfData.csv.gz file uncorrupted. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The man page says

> Esxtop  in
>          batch  mode  runs  until it produces the number of iterations requested
>          (see command-line option n below for  more  details)  or  until  killed
>          using CTRL c.

It makes no other mention of signals.

I would try a simple experiment. In another terminal I would run the command again with a different output filename

```
esxtop –b –a –d 10 –n 2000| gzip -9c > test.csv.gz
```

I would let it collect data for a short time and hen type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. Inspect the output and see if it is corrupted or not.

You could try a similar experiment by sending a `HUP` to the test process.